# Have complex manifolds with dual number structure on the holomorphic tangent bundle been studied?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics

If $M$ denotes a $2n$-dimensional *real* smooth manifold, then $M$ together with

- $J\in\operatorname{End}(TM)$ with $J^2 =\mathrm{id}$ (also called almost product structure on $M$) have been surveyed in detail in the rather dated *Gadea, Cruceanu, Fortuny - A Survey on Paracomplex Geometry (1996)*

and

- $J\in\operatorname{End}(TM)$ with $J^2 =0$ (also called almost dual number structure) have been studied in detail (within a larger class) by Shirokov, Shurygin, Vishnevskii and others.

Let $M$ now denote a $4n$-dimensional *complex* manifold and let $J\in\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(T^{1,0}M)$ be an *almost dual number structure* on the holomorphic tangent bundle.

> Have complex manifolds with such additional (almost-) dual number structures $(M,J)$ already been studied and if so, what are some references?

It was mentioned to me that (almost) dual number structures are important to physicists for some reason, but I am unsure if this was referring to the real or to the complex case or both. Also, he couldn't recall a precise reference, and my search has been unfruitful as I am quite unfamiliar with the mathematical physics venue.

Any pointers would be appreciated!